# Android - Keyboard compresses my View

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, keyboard, viewport

i'm working on an Android/iOS Application. When the Keyboard opens up for the login (username and password) all gets shrinked together and it looks like this:

[image]

normaly it should not be compressed. It should move up, and give me a clear view on what i'm typing.

[image]

Yes, so i don't know, what to do. I tried to work with percentages in the whole app (width/height) - maybe this is the reason, why my View gets not moved up but shrinked?

I looked around here at stack and found some suggestions like:

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

or `adjustResize` instead, but nothing of that worked for me. On iOS all works fine. What i want the view to do is that he just moves a bit up, and nothing gets resized.

I hope you can help me and if you need more information, please let me know, i'll update or comment my Question then.

- Cordova 3.5
- jQuery/jQuery-Mobile
- Plugins: Camera/Console/Device/Dialogs/File-Transfer/File/inappbrowser/Splashscreen/Statusbar/vibration/geolocation/network-information
- Eclipse with Genymotion emulator
- Devices: Galaxy Note 10.1, 4.4.2; Xperia Z2 4.4.2

This is what my Androidmanifest looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="de.*****************.de" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="********" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: try this:: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was stuck with the same problem, few days ago.

As you said, you have given height and width in percentage.

When the android keyboard appears the window is resized and its height is the screen size excluding the keyboard size.

Giving height in percentage to the main container of your page, (i.e. to the body tag)  will shrink the height of your page when the keyboard appears,

Setting the min-height for the body tag once on `document.ready` worked for me.

```
$(function(){

$("body").css("min-height",$(window).height())

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, intelliJ Amiya and NaeemShaikh27 - i'm going to test this later in the evening.

Answer (score 2):

Add this In your manifest .I hope it will works. For more information Do Click [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

**`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"`**

Comment: Those values didn't work for me, but `adjustPan` did the trick

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro okay